# Python3: Autcomplete text using CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, autocomplete

What I want to make is an autocomplete script, that uses a csv file where you’d get the most likely suggestion from user input, using the 2nd row of the csv (which states the number of occurences of the given word) to determine likeliness.

So far I’ve been testing out two methods after importing the CSV, the first is to make it into a sorted list (highest numbers first). Which I would then loop through and output the first encountered word that starts with user input. However this idea got fundamentally flawed by that I can’t find a solution to sort the list based on the actual value of the numbers, only the beginning numbers. Eg. that the number nine (9) gets listed higher than 7184.

```
thelist = open('alphabetical.csv', 'r')
csv1 = csv.reader(thelist, delimiter = ',')
sortedlist = sorted(csv1, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

A snippet could look like:
[[’with’, ’1671’], [’seldom’, ’2’], [’green’, ’246’]] – and so forth.

This is what the function currently looks like:

```
def main():
"""Initialize main loop."""
word = ""

while word != "q":
    word = input("Type word: ").lower()
    print("Autocompletion finished: ", autocomplete())

def autocomplete():
"""Return autocomplete suggestions."""
filtered_words = filter(lambda x: x.startswith(word), sortedlist)
return filtered_words
```

The result after input is:

```
<filter object at 0x7fbfb27ca860>
```

I know the code is flawed, and that there’s more to it, so there’s no surprise to me that the output isn’t what it needs to be.

My fear after getting the given output from the current function is that it’s impossible to use a list, and such I’m currently experimenting with dictionary instead, but the last thing I want is to go about a new solution when I was actually on the right track to begin with. So I turn to you for any possible guidance and suggestions for how to solve this.

Thank you.

Comment: python 3 filter needs list: `filtered_words = list(filter(lambda x: x[1].startswith(word), sortedlist))`

Comment: also, your way of sorting is cumbersome. and turning to list won't work because you've put rows of your csv file, not the string.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what the size of your autocomplete lexicon is, but I would recommend representing your lexicon of completions as a Multiway Trie on which you can perform BFS/DFS instead of using a sorted list

Comment: @NiemaMoshiri I'm intrigued, wasn't aware of that method as I'm a beginner in programming altogether. I will do more research on that, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

first, why sorting then creating a new list?

```
sort = sorted(csv1, key = lambda x: x[1])
for row in sort:
    sortedlist.append(row)
```

could be

```
sortedlist = sorted(csv1, key = lambda x: x[1])
```

your other mistake(s): `filter` no longer returns a list in python 3, it's *lazily evaluated*. You have to *force* list iteration on it.

If you do that you realize that there's another error, because `startswith` applies to the *row*, not to the string.

So a quickfix would be:

```
filtered_words = list(filter(lambda x: x[0].startswith(word), sortedlist))
```

that would return the rows, not the words, BTW.

but using `list` + `filter` + `lambda` is becoming cumbersome and not performant. Prefer a simple list comprehension:

```
filtered_words = [x for x in sortedlist if x[0].startswith(word)]
```

that returns the rows as well. To get only the words you can use unpacking for both fields and discard the number

```
filtered_words = [x for x,_ in sortedlist if x.startswith(word)]
```

or you could have discarded the numbers right from the start:

```
sortedlist = [x[0] for x in sorted(csv1, key = lambda x: x[1])]
```

which makes you change the filter:

```
filtered_words = [x for x in sortedlist if x.startswith(word)]
```

this method is simple but as noted in comments, it's not the most efficient because it implies a linear search (and doesn't take advantage of the fact that the list is sorted)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the cumbersome sortedlist was indeed from debugging, I should have posted it the way suggest to begin with, however the result is the same, eg. not sorting as intended. 

I will look into your suggestions on list comprehension and see if I can find a solution, much appreciated!